# How do I make a data file available to unit tests?

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

I'm using VS2008 TFS (with MSTest).

I have a unit test that works reliably, relying on a data file in a subfolder of the project (ie testproject1\TestData). The data file properties are Build Action=Content, Copy Always. (It is not a test datafile as such, but a file that the production code reads and normally expects in its own folder)

When the test is built and executes, the data file is correctly copied to the ...\TestResults\(testruniD)\Out folder, and the tested code finds it.

Now, I move the test and its data file to another test project in the solution (where it really should be), The data file is in the same folder relative to the new test project (testproject2\TestData), and the data file properties are checked as still being as above. However on rebuild the test fails in the new location because the data file has not been copied to the test results output folder so the executing code cannot find it.

Is there something extra I should have done to ensure the data file is still copied?

I've had a related problem before, whereby some data files are copied to the test results output folder and some are not, for no apparent reason, and it bewilders me.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx) attribute ([more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx)).

Edit: As per the OP, [the .testrunconfig file must also be edited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227713/626853).

Comment: Thanks. That's part of the answer - but you also need to enable deployment in the testrun config, I've found.

Comment: @NeilHaughton: Aha - I had forgotten about that, since I (fortunately) haven't used MSTest for a while. If you have a link to an article about it, please post it here, and I'll include it the answer (as reference for others that might stumble across this post).

Comment: I found it somewhere in a similar question on StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227545/how-can-i-get-copy-to-output-directory-to-work-with-unit-tests?rq=1, I think

Answer (score 7):

I know this is late. The accepted answer is technically right. However, over the years I have found that the **DeploymentAttribute** approach becomes cumbersome when you have too many data files. In my case it was nearing thousand.  The problems were

1. Remember to mark every file as **Copy to output** .
2. Every time I would debug the project, the thousand data files would get copied over to *MyUnitTestProject\Bin\Debug*. This slowed down my overall development and debugging experience.

**Proposed solution**

My proposed solution is let the data files remain as static files in the Unit testing project and simply determine the absolute path using the *Location* property of the executing *System.Reflection.Assembly*.  This has worked really well for me, considering the large number of data files I was dealing with.  Worked well when the tests ran on *Jenkins* build server.

You can refer to the code snippet I have posted in another answer.
[NUnit DeploymentItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378276/nunit-deploymentitem/52949597#52949597)

**Drawback with my proposed solution**

You do not get a new deployment folder created every time your tests run. If your unit tests are going to create output files, then you are responsible for generating a new folder under the location of the unit testing assembly, which would be usually *MyUnitTestProject\Bin\Debug*.

**Posting the code here because my hyperlinked answer was deleted**
Somebody by the name Martijn Pieters deleted my original answer because he did not like the duplication. Therefore I am reproducing the original code here.

```
    internal static string GetFullPathToFile(string pathRelativeUnitTestingFile)
{
    string folderProjectLevel = GetPathToCurrentUnitTestProject();
    string final = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderProjectLevel, pathRelativeUnitTestingFile);
    return final;
}
/// <summary>
/// Get the path to the current unit testing project.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private static string GetPathToCurrentUnitTestProject()
{
    string pathAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    string folderAssembly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pathAssembly);
    if (folderAssembly.EndsWith("\\") == false) folderAssembly = folderAssembly + "\\";
    string folderProjectLevel = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(folderAssembly + "..\\..\\");
    return folderProjectLevel;
}
```